# Reading rows and table locked for updating

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Locks
Hello all, I am working on locks and trying to understand them.

My goal is too, be able to lock a row while it is being updated but still allow users to be able to read from the table.
 In my reading I read this

*"Shared locks (S)
Shared locks are held on data being read under the pessimistic concurrency model. While a shared lock is being held other transactions can read but can't modify locked data. "*

So I have this in one transaction.

```
BEGIN TRAN

USE AdventureWorks2008R2

UPDATE Person.Address 
SET AddressLine2 = 'Test Address 2'
WHERE AddressId = 5
```

Now in a next transaction I have the same thing

```
BEGIN TRAN

USE AdventureWorks2008R2



UPDATE Person.Address 
SET AddressLine2 = 'gar'
WHERE AddressId = 5

--ROLLback
```

Which doesn't get executed as I expect but in another transaction I have

```
select * from AdventureWorks2008R2.Person.Address
```

This last transction doesn't get run, And I am not exactly sure why. Since it said I can READ the data

I also looked at the update lock it seems to work because, I cannot update the row unless I comit or rollback the transction. HOWEVER, I cannot select the transaction. Is my only available option is to use an exclusive lock and read uncommitted?
Just looking for the best way to lock the row being updated but at the same time allow that row and the table to be read.
Thank you.

Comment: Use Snapshot Isolation Level in your transactions.

Comment: Show full code.  Are you committing and ending the transaction.  You do know a single update is a transaction?

Comment: @Blam I am not ending the transactions, I am beginning the transctions and going to other sessions and noting what is happening when I try to access and update said row. Testing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what mode the lock on the resource is taken out in.

There are three lock modes of relevance here. Shared (S), Update (U) and Exclusive (X).

The lock compatibility matrix is as follows

```
+---+----+----+---+
|   | S  | U  | X |
+---+----+----+---+
| S | ✓  | ✓ | ✘ |
| U | ✓  | ✘ | ✘ |
| X | ✘  | ✘ | ✘ |
+---+----+----+---+
```

i.e. Shared is compatible with other Shared or update. Update locks are compatible with shared locks but not other update locks and exclusive locks aren't compatible with anything.

The first transaction gets a U lock on it then converts that to an X lock to actually perform the update. The second transaction gets blocked because S locks aren't compatible with X locks.

The only way of allowing a row to be read whilst being updated would be to use `read uncommitted` or one of the snapshot isolation levels. The latter would return the "before" value of the row. The former could return "dirty" data. i.e. the "after" value but before it was committed.

Comment: Thought at first there was another select in there. Only two transactions so even simpler.